# Node JS Stored Procedure field values returning as undefined

Tags: node.js

I am new to learning node, so sorry for a noob question.
I have mysql running and stored proc returning fields.
I want to assign the values to string variables and loop through each row.
I do this alot in c#, but I am too much of a noob on node.

The results in the console are.

```
console.log(one)  -> 
[RowDataPacket {

CitySearchSearchEngineID: 1,

SearchURL: 'https://www.url.com' } ]

 OkPacket {

  fieldCount: 0,......
}
```

This above is good, however,

console.log(one.SearchURL); -> undefined

I have been struggling with this for a while now and can't figure out why I can't get the value out. I have tried a handful of different methods. If I do JSON.stringify it will give the row to a string just fine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Code below.

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'secretpassword',
   database: 'DB1',
   port: 3306
 });

 db.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});

db.query('CALL esp_Select_SearchURLs()', function(err, rows){
  if(err) throw err;

  _.each(rows, function(one){

    console.log(one);  // returns back in console the RowPacketData
    console.log(one.SearchURL); // returns back undefined.

  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like your `one` is array for some reason, can you add log `console.log('one is %s isArray: %s', (typeof one), Array.isArray(one))`, if it true try `console.log(one[0].SearchURL)`

Comment: console.log(one[0].SearchURL) does seem to work. Thanks. now I need to figure out how to only get the rows that have data.

Comment: The OkPacket stuff was causing most of my issues.

Comment: if(one.constructor.name != 'OkPacket') {
            console.log(one[0].SearchURL);
         }

Comment: Good, so I make it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the OkPacket information was interfering with picking up the info from the array.

```
    if(one.constructor.name != 'OkPacket') { 
       console.log(one[0].SearchURL);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `one` is an Array for some reason, so try `console.log(one[0].SearchURL)` should work fine.